# Retrieving an iPhone photo saved to the photo library

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, photo-management

I am saving images to the photo library and would like to retrieve them dynamically to display in future launches of my app.  I use the WriteToSavedPhotosAlbum function, as below, but do not get any info to access the saved photo programmatically.

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage *image, id completionTarget, SEL completionSelector, void *contextInfo);
```

Once saved, is there a way to retrieve the file name/id and load an image from the photo library at a later time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to save them for yourself.
Possibly in your app's documents or cache folder.

As a side note, when you say: "display at launch", if you mean to replace the Default.png, that won't work.

The launch image must be static and included in your app bundle.

If not, disregard.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  By "display at launch" I just meant load one of them in the initial view on display.

Comment: Default.png can be a symbolic link to something outside the bundle, though. http://collison.ie/blog/2008/11/dynamic-defaultpng-files-on-the-iphone

Answer (score 2):

You can't, unless the user picks the photo using the `UIImagePickerController`.
Check this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818369/how-can-i-load-images-from-a-users-photo-album-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

try this code segment make the necessay changes

UIImagePickerController *picker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

picker.delegate=pickerDelegate;

picker.sourcetype=UIImagepickerControllerSourceTypePhtoLibrary;