# Path of photos folder in ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, photo

I am trying to make a ipad app which would upload the latest synced photos on an ipad to a web server.

I found a great reference for how to upload a file by http here.
[How can I upload a photo to a server with the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125306/how-can-i-upload-a-photo-to-a-server-with-the-iphone)

However what should be the path to the photos folder?

It would be great if somebody can suggest an example for

1. Listing all directory in the photos application.
2. How to enumerate a file in a directory/album and get its path.

I am really new to iOS devleopment. Sorry if i am bit vague.

Answer (score 4):

Appears to be in /var/mobile/Media/DCIM/ .

Reference: http://www.macstories.net/ipad/ipad-photos-documents-finder-mac/

Answer (score 0):

Refer - [How can I load images from a user's photo album on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818369/how-can-i-load-images-from-a-users-photo-album-on-the-iphone)